# Is Long Beach Poly in same league as De La Salle?

Tags: plot-explanation, when-the-game-stands-tall

I'm not from the US so don't know college football but I do watch a lot NFL.

In the movie **[When the Game Stands Tall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2247476/)** they talk about playing against Long Beach Polytechnic (Poly) because all the other teams are scared. So is Poly in the same league or a higher league?

How come Poly have 100 players and De La Salle has to use his players in both defense and offense? Are De La Salle struggling to find the budget to support a bigger team or is it because they're in a lower league that they've simply got less staff?

Comment: I have no knowledge of this film, but the [synopsis on IMDB](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qvLc33WRrJ8J:www.imdb.com/title/tt2247476/synopsis+&cd=17&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) strongly indicates that De La Salle is an underprivileged school in a moderately poor area with only a couple of full time staff members. The match is made against another high school team (Poly) but one from a much more affluent area. This means that the two teams are at the same level (high school league champions), but not part of the same league system.

Comment: @Richard So will be fair make a Formula1 comparasion. With Poly is like Ferrary with a very big budget and De la Salle is like an inferior team Manor or Sauber with very low budget?

Answer (score 1):

I actually went to Long Beach Poly high school so I can provide some background. Long Beach Poly is in a poor and "hood" area actually, we have our football games at a separate field because we can't afford to redo ours. We have a lot of players because our school is very big, almost 5 thousand student's bc it's a public school, not private that you have to pay for like DE LA Salle. A lot of people join our football team because we've had the most students go on to play in the NFL and it's a way out of the hood honestly. The movie should have been about us honestly. We are the underdogs haha. And yes, we were I'm the same league as them as well, I think it's called PAC-12.